# Best way to retrieve nearest geopoints (lat/long) to the one given by user, i have the list of all geopoints stored in a MySQL database

Tags: java, database, web-services, geolocation

I'm trying to create a mobile application, that capture the user current geopoint(lat/long) send it to a web service and the web service returns the 5 nearest geopoints from the a long list. What i don't have clear is how can i get the 5 nearest geopoints (my initial approach was, getting all the points from the datebase then calculate the distance between each geopoint and the user geopoint and provide with the 5 nearest to him) that is not so costly proccesing wise. Any suggestion on how could i do it? If need more info let me know so i can repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, and how optimal you need this to be will likely depend on the number of points you have (so it scales well).

For spatial queries, you should use a database that supports spatial indexing, which allows for much faster searches. PostGIS is one example, and there are GIS extensions for MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html.

Here is a sample solution to the k-nearest-neighbor problem in PostGIS http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic

EDIT: You can also use techniques that use [geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), but be sure to read the limitations carefully in this article.

Comment: I will use the Spatial Queries. I'll post when i'm done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In our [contact adress search on esperanto.de](http://www.esperanto.de/dej/landaj_asocioj/adresoj.php) we use a variant of this SQL statement (wrapped in PHP syntax):

```
$demando =
  "SELECT DISTINCT id, [...]" .
  "   AVG(tie.longitudo) AS longitudo, AVG(tie.latitudo) AS latitudo, ".
  "   ROUND(111.3 *  SQRT( POW(({$chi[latitudo]} - AVG(tie.latitudo)),2) + " .
  "                        POW((({$chi[longitudo]} - AVG(tie.longitudo)) * COS(({$chi[latitudo]} + AVG(tie.latitudo)) / 114.6 )),2) )) " .
  "       AS efektiva_distanco " .
  " FROM MA_Adresoj, gxustaj_plzkoord AS tie " .
  " WHERE ( " . $pliaj_restriktoj . ") " .
  "  and (tie.plz = urba_kodo) " .
  " GROUP BY id, urba_kodo, nomo_pers, nomo_fam, adresaldono, strato, loko," .
  "          telefono, retadreso " .
  " HAVING efektiva_distanco < '" . $distanco . "' " .
  " ORDER BY " . $ordo;
```

to filter all entries within a given distance (`$distanco`). It is a bit complicated by the fact that we need to average out several coordinates for a single post code (which should have been done on the coordinate database, but isn't.)

The core is the distance calculation depending on longitude and latitude (in degrees) here:

```
111.3 *  SQRT( POW(here.latitude - there.latitude),2) +
               POW((here.longitude - there.longitude) * COS( (here.latitude + there.latitude) / 114.6 ),2) ))
```

(The result is the distance in kilometers.)

I'm not sure if this formula works universally or is somehow approximate for Germany (or only smaller distances - I think it will calculate a too big distance when one point is north and the other south of the equator with similar absolute latitudes ... and also when there is a big east-west difference).

Of course, this will get quite slow if you have many points - then you'll either have to do some pre-filtering like in iluxas answer, or better use a database with spatial indexing.

Answer (score -1):

```
select x, y, sqrt((x-userX)^2, (y-userY)^2) as distance from points
where x > userX - 10 and x < userX + 10
and y > userY - 10 and y < userY + 10
order by distance asc
limit 5
```

syntax very approximate, of course

Comment: This works only if you are sure there are at least 5 points in the circle or radius 20 around the point. And your distance calculation does only work near the equator this way - for other locations you'll have to add corrections, since the earth is not flat.

Comment: It's the best to do the algorithm of calculating distance in the database layer? Suppose i have 3 layer, Client(the mobile application), Application (web service that receive query and sent back response) and database layer (Contains all the points [lat/long])

Comment: I was thinking of using Haversine Formula which takes in account the earth radius. I'm not looking to limit the radius of the search. I'm looking to provide the client this scenario: 5 nearest geopoints filtering by city and type of service (gas station, pharmacy, restaurant).

Comment: no, don't use sqrt(). It is a very slow function. Order by squared distance, will give you much better results.